# How to make RestKit working with ARC in iOS 5?

Tags: xcode, ios5, restkit

Has one anyone managed to fixed all the errors when linking RestKit with the iOS 5 project with ARC enabled? If so please share the library.

On the other hand after doing my fair share of research the Author will be releasing this in 0.9.6 and he has explained something on how to get around this for now. But im new to the scene and dont understand to do what he says. Can someone please give simple instructions.

Visit http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/msg/b14305789f5bdec4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a user of the library **you don't need to worry about it** . RestKit is a seperate target in your porject therefore RestKit itself can be non-ARC and it will be fine if the rest of your project **is** ARC-enabled. If you are running into problems that you think are related to ARC, you are probably integrating it wrong.

As a user of the library you won't noticed any benefit if the author decides to make it ARC-enabled or not.

If your project is ARC-enabled, you can use RestKit without worring about retain/release fo the RestKit object you use.

Answer (score 2):

I made a new ARC xcode project, put my sources in it, and then followed the install instructions exactly. Exactly. Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a "no known class method" ARC Issue error after updating my RestKit git submodule.

I fixed this by deleting derived data (xcode organizer > projects > projectName > delete derived data).